# Like to Migrate from MariaDB 10 to Persona Mysql 5.7? What is the best way to upgrade?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, percona, mysql-5.7

I like to migrate  from MariaDB 10 to Persona Mysql 5.7? What is the best way to upgrade? I am planning to take full database backup and import into Persona Mysql 5.7 and run mysql_upgrade.

Comment: That sounds good.  There could be glitches due to the differences between the 10 and 5.7.  Try the migration; you will soon be the expert on it.  Let us know what you find.